# Better declaration of a constant with generated value

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, lazy-evaluation

What declaration would be better in Kotlin and why?

`Key` here is always same value

```
private val key: ByteArray by lazy {
    byteArrayOf(some static bytes)
}
```

Or

```
private val key = byteArrayOf(some static bytes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the static bytes are the same, adding a lazy delegate isn't going to buy you anything. Lazy is useful if the value being calculated requires some computational effort (time and/or space), or possibly isn't required in some cases. So you'd only want to initialize it when you really need it, not every time.

In fact, if you do need it every time, adding the lazy delegate is going to just add overhead. I would do the easiest thing and only go for the lazy delegate if I find it would help through benchmarking or testing.

TLDR: Stick with initializing the array directly, unless you don't need it every time AND it requires serious resources to create.